# CSS align element right not working

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon!

Im currently creating a widget style review element on a website and I want the `</a>` tag and the span that contains a star rating image(shown bellow) to be on the right side of the div. The `</a>` tag is placed in the position that I want it. The problem I got stuck on is how to place the span beneath it also aligned right.

```
  <div class="one-half last feedbackcompany review" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <h3>ONZE BEOORDELINGEN</h3>
    <p class="large-number">9</p>
    <p class="small-number">5</p>
    <a>Lees alle 1123 reviews</a>
    <span class="rating-stars-small stars"></span>
  </div>
```

And my CSS

```
.review {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    color:black;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-top: 10px solid #f05a28;
}

.review .stars {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}

.review .large-number {
    font-size: 55px;
    line-height: 54px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.review .small-number {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
  .rating-stars-small {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 19px;
  display: block;
  background: url('../images/rating-stars-small.png') no-repeat left center;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 8px; 
  }

.review h3 {
    margin: 10px !important;
}

.review a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    color:black;
}

.review p {
    float:left;
}
```

Currently looking like this:

[image: Currently looking like this]

Comment: Can you show the css for `rating-stars-small`?

Comment: .rating-stars-small {
  width: 100%;
  height: 19px;
  display: block;
  background: url('../images/rating-stars-small.png') no-repeat left center;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
 }

Comment: A element is just a <a></a>

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
.rating-stars-small { 
width: 100%;
height: 19px; 
display: inline-block;
background: url('../images/rating-stars-small.png') no-repeat leftcenter;
float: right;//or text align try out which is better
margin-bottom: 8px; 
}
```

Comment: is that what you wanted?

Comment: No I want the stars to be floated right under the <a>

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/sHE_WOXrQB_WdvRuw3r0aw.png here it is under your <a> element

Comment: maybe you can try to replace display: block; for display: inline-block;

Comment: Not working either, maybe because it gets overridden somewhere

Comment: then you have to try to add !important in your css(float:right !important; for example)

Comment: I have it like this now: http://prntscr.com/i8psz1

but the stars need with some margin under the <A> instead of this blankspace

Answer (score 1):

change your  tag to this:

```
.review a {
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    color:black;
}
```

and your html to this:

```
    <div class="one-half last feedbackcompany review" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <h3>ONZE BEOORDELINGEN</h3>
        <p class="large-number">9</p>
        <p class="small-number">5</p>
        <div style="position:relative;float:right;">
            <a>Lees alle 1123 reviews</a>
            <span class="rating-stars-small stars">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

if you want to give a same positioning to 2 or more tags put them in a new  tag. and if you want  to be under  you must position  as relative in that way  consumes it's own position and other tags would place themselves in order to .
i hope this helps you with your code. 
sorry for the aaaaaaa...'s i didnt have the uri of your image so i used aaaa... instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make a css call to align the stars. Try and fix in align = 'right' inside ur span tag. OR make a CSS call to .star{} and set ur align to right.